# create array from returned values

Tags: javascript

I'm looping over an object (and parsing out elements) and my console.log reads:

```
["item 1"]
["item 2"]
["item 3"]
```

etc.

I'm simply trying create a new array that looks like:

```
["item 1","item 2","item 3"];
```

Comment: so where is your original data? and what is the question?

Comment: You need to create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried push() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `console.log( x );` with `result.push( x[0] );` and add `var result = [];` before your loop. Then `result` will contain the array you want when the loop completes.

Comment: My issue was that I var'd the empty array within the loop, so moving it outside worked. Thanks.